# Canonical morphism of dualizing sheaves under normalization.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, singularity-theory

The following appears in a paper by Hwang and Oguiso.

> Let $V'$ be a complex variety with the property that
> its normalization is smooth and the dualizing sheaf $ω_{V'}$ is invertible. Denoting
> by $ν: V \to V'$ the normalization map, we have a natural injective sheaf map
> $ω_V \to ν^* ω_{V'}$.

*My question:* How is the sheaf map $\omega_V \to \nu^* \omega_{V'}$ defined?

I think this may be related to Hartshorne, **Exercise III 7.2**

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a finite morphism of projective schemes of the same dimension over a field $k$, and let $\omega_X$ be a dualizing sheaf for $Y$.
>
> 1. Show that $f^! \omega_Y$ is a dualizing sheaf for $X$.
> 2. If $X$ and $Y$ are both nonsingular, and $k$ algebraically closed, conclude that there is a natural trace map $t: f_* \omega_X \to \omega_Y$.

The trace map from 2. actually exists for the dualizing sheaves, even if $Y$ is not smooth, so I do get a morphism

$$ f_* \omega_{V} \to \omega_{V'},$$

but taking the pull-back yields $f^* f_* \omega_V \to f^* \omega_{V'}$, which is not the desired result.

Comment: Which paper? ${}{}$

Comment: @KReiser [Characteristic foliation on the discriminant hypersurface of a holomorphic Lagrangian fibration](https://doi.org/10.1353/ajm.0.0062). They actually work in the context of analytic spaces, maybe this changes anything?

Comment: @KReiser The quote appears in the paragraph preceding Lemma 4.2.

Comment: I don't think the fact that we're dealing with analytic spaces should matter. It's always true  that for a resolution of singularities $f:X\to Y$ with $\omega_Y$ a line bundle we have $\omega_X\cong f^*\omega_Y\otimes \mathcal{O}(D)$ where $D$ is supported on the exceptional locus. But there's no a priori reason that $\mathcal{O}(D)$ should be of the form they're after here, so you need something specific to your situation to imply that (I don't see it yet).

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for your answer. What's a good reference for the isomorphism $\omega_X \cong f^* \omega_Y \otimes \mathcal O(D)$?

Comment: This is just the fact that formation of the dualizing sheaf commutes with restriction to opens (this can be found in Hartshorne's *Residues and Duality*, B. Conrad's book on Duality, or Stacks) and observing that the normalization map is an isomorphism when restricted to the complement of the exceptional locus. So $\omega_X\otimes (f^*\omega_Y)^{-1}$ is an invertible sheaf which is trivial on the complement of the exceptional locus and therefore is the sheaf associated to a divisor contained in the exceptional locus by the standard correspondence.

Comment: I should warn you that this relied on $\omega_Y$ being a line bundle via the assumptions in the post - you can say something similar if $\omega_Y$ is $\Bbb Q$-Cartier, but in general one does not have this sort of statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I benefit a lot from the answer from Sándor Kovács, see [Inclusion of (pulling back of) dualizing sheaves under normalization](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448370/inclusion-of-pulling-back-of-dualizing-sheaves-under-normalization?noredirect=1#comment1158722_448370), and I write the details of this question here.

Now, $V^\prime$ is a complex variety such that $\omega_{V^\prime}$ is locally free, this will be satisfied if $V$ is Gorenstein for instance. Taking the normalization $\mu:V\rightarrow V^\prime$ then  we know that $\omega_V$ is reflexive thus torsion free anyhow.

As you have noted, we have the  map
$$\rho:\mu^*\mu_*\omega_V \rightarrow \mu^* \omega_{V^\prime}$$ by pulling back the trace map. And, since $\mu$ is finite, we have the following short exact sequence:
$$0\rightarrow \mathcal T\rightarrow \mu^*\mu_*\omega_V \rightarrow \omega_V\rightarrow 0$$
where $\mathcal T$ is the torsion subsheaf of $\mu^*\mu_*\omega_V$. The first thing one should observe that is $\rho$ must factor through $\omega_V$. This is because that $\mu^*\omega_{V^\prime}$ is locally free thus torsion free. Then one can define a (well-defined) map as follows (abuse some notations):
$$\iota: \omega_V\rightarrow \mu^* \omega_{V^\prime}, \quad a\mapsto\rho(a^\prime)$$
where $a^\prime$ is any lift of $a$  in $\mu^*\mu_*\omega_V.$

The finial issue that $\textrm{Ker }(\iota)=0$ is then obvious as we have mentioned that $\omega_V$ is indeed torsion free.

---

Some comments: the assumption that $\omega_{V^\prime}$ is locally free is crucial here, since we need the pull-back of it is torsion free. However, without some extra assumption(such as flat), the pull back of reflexive may not be reflexive. Similarly, pull back of torsion free sheaves also may not be torsion free, see Jean RUPPENTHAL & Martin SERA's paper  [Modifications of torsion-free coherent analytic sheaves](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.3080.pdf).

Comment: Excellent solution.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I had somewhat given up on this, because in the situation Hang and Oguiso have, on can also do this explicitly by dealing with the case for curves.

Comment: @red_trumpet, you're welcome!